# The Gysin map for a singular hypersurface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective complex manifold and $Y\subset X$ be an irreducible 
hypersurface. If $Y$ is *smooth*, there is a well known Gysin sequence. 
However, even if $Y$ is not smooth, a kind of Gysin map can still be devised.

Consider a desingularization $f:\widetilde{Y}\to Y$ and the inclusion 
$i:Y\hookrightarrow X$. We have two maps

$H^i(Y,\mathbb{Q})\to H^i(\widetilde{Y},\mathbb{Q})\to H^{i+2}(X,\mathbb{Q});$

the first one is $f^*$ and the second one is the Poincare dual to $(i\circ f)^*$
(essentially the Gysin map). I am convinced that the composition does not depend on 
desingularization, though I do not know a rigorous proof of this.

*QUESTION*: Is the sequence

$H^i(Y,\mathbb{Q})\to H^{i+2}(X,\mathbb{Q})\to H^{i+2}(X\setminus Y,\mathbb{Q})$

exact (as it is in the smooth case)?

All I know about it is a result of Deligne 
[Theorie de Hodge III. Publ. Math. IHES 44 (1974) pp. 5–77.; Corollary 8.2.8]
that

$H^i(\widetilde{Y},\mathbb{Q})\to H^{i+2}(X,\mathbb{Q})\to H^{i+2}(X\setminus Y,\mathbb{Q})$

is exact, but this is much weaker than what I need.

Comment: If you work with Chow groups rather than cohomology, a version of this exact sequence is given (with much weaker hypotheses than the ones you have specified) in Fulton's *Intersection Theory*, Proposition 1.8, page 21. This is not quite what you are asking for, but it suggests that something similar is probably true for cohomology.

Comment: Thank you. Though I am not sure if it may be helpful. 


Comment: When $Y$ is smooth, by Poincar\'e duality, the sequence you consider is the dual sequence of the sequence with compact supports $\dots H^{2n-i-2}_c(X\backslash Y,{\bf Q})\to H^{2n-i-2}(X,{\bf Q})\to H^{2n-i-2}(Y,{\bf Q})\to\dots$ This suggests that the "right sequence" without compact supports should be obtained by dualising the above sequence using Grothendieck-Verdier duality (which generalizes Poincar\'e duality to the non-smooth setting). In particular, you would expect the dualising complex to appear on $Y$ (and not just $\bf Q$). 

Comment: Perhaps, but I hope that the statement may be true as it is. 
I do not need the Whole Gysin sequence after all.